# How to intercept and cache all disk writes in Linux?

Tags: linux

I made a stupid mistake and didn't make a backup before fiddling with LVM RAID settings.

I attempted to upgrade a RAID 5 to a RAID 6 with LVM and something just didn't work right I guess. I found config backups in the LVM RAID metadata extent (I was really grasping at straws when I found it; I didn't actually think I'd find anything useful there).

The idea is to apply these config backups to LVM using `vgcfgrestore`, however I would like to avoid all disk writes to the disks themselves in case something goes wrong (i.e., a sync/rescan/parity update with a wrong config which could overwrite my actual data that I believe is still there).

I'm very familiar with doing this at a filesystem level with OverlayFS, but I'm working with block devices here so I'm out of my element. I've been doing some research, and everything I've found doesn't quite seem to fit the bill for this scenario.

- `dm-snapshot` copies the original data into the snapshot volume, which will be in RAM, so I'd really rather not risk it in case of power failure or something.
- `dm-writecache` seemed to be a good choice, but it doesn't seem like you can prevent writeback all-together (maybe with a really high autocommit_time, but I'd still be afraid of RAM-limited autocommit_blocks). Even still, I'm not sure what can send a FLUSH message, but that'd be potentially disastrous if it did happen.

Is there any way to either:

1. Delay all writes to specific (or all) block devices indefinitely, or
2. Cache all writes onto a separate block device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get ahold of my data, but it wasn't without its trials and tribulations -- not the least of which is that all data on the drives (other than the LVM and RAID metadata) was encrypted, so I couldn't manually validate my RAID configuration before just trying it.

I manually reconstructed the RAID described in one of the configs in the RAID metadata using `dmsetup`. When I went to do the final RAID assembly, I used a command like:

```
printf "%s\n" "0 23439925248 raid raid6_n_6 4 128 nosync region_size 16384 5 254:0 254:5 254:1 254:6 254:2 254:7 254:3 254:8 254:4  254:9" | dmsetup create RAID_Data
```

Which is perfectly valid, according to the kernel documentation for the dm-raid device. However, there is a particular issue with RAID6 and and the `nosync` option, which prevented the raid6_n_6 device from being created, leaving a dmesg error of:

```
device-mapper: table: 254:10: raid: Invalid flags combination
```

Apparently, nosync is not usable with RAID6.

My working solutions was to:

1. Setup read-only loop devices for each of my LVM PV's using `losetup -r [loop_dev] [PV_device]`
2. Use `dmsetup create` to re-create the rmeta and rimage devices using the read-only loop devices.
3. Create my final dm-raid device, removing the `nosync` option without fear of a sync destroying data (since the dm-raid device is built on dm devices that reference a read-only loop device rather than the actual disks).

I'm just really glad that I was paying close attention while converting my RAID or I may not have got my data back at all.

For anybody that stumbles upon this later on: region_size and stripe_size in the LVM config file is a direct argument to dmsetup (i.e., it's a dm block count, not an LVM extent count).

**EDIT**: I wasn't very clear in the question originally as to the events that led to my problem. The command that caused this issue was a conversion from raid6_n_6 to a striped volume, which in itself should be safe. The command I ran was `lvconvert --type striped --stripes 1 vg/lv`. LVM should *not* have allowed this to happen probably, but it did.

Either way, the conversion was instant and did not require a scrub. Therefore, I was certain my data was still available, just disconnected from the volume. Because the volume was converted to a striped volume, a live system was able to automatically mount and activate the LV without the potential for data loss due to an automatic scrub. Of course, since chunks were missing, I was not able to mount my encrypted volume within the LV where all my data was stored (this was also my first indication that there may be a problem).

From the live system, I set up a filter in lvm.conf to filter out the real block devices and mapped those devices to read-only loop devices for safety purposes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Power off the system
2. Buy a forensic disk controller aka hardware write-block device
3. Make a 1:1 copy of all drives using the forensic disk controller
4. Work on the copies when you try to recover your data
5. Make backups!

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I was looking for a reasonably safe software solution.